# Change detection in Angular freezes browser

Tags: javascript, angular

I have function permission() that works perfectly, but when I call function deleteChannel() it freezes my browser.

```
async havePermission(channelId) {
        if (await this.isPrivateChannel2(channelId) && !(await this.inChannel(channelId))) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

async permission(channelId) {
        console.log(await this.havePermission(channelId));
        return await this.havePermission(channelId);
    }
}
```

Use it in template:

```
<app-chat *ngIf="permission(channelId) | async" [channelId]="channelId"></app-chat>
```

deleteChannel function:

```
 deleteChannel(channel) {
            this.channelId = channel.$key;
            this.channels.remove(this.channelId);
            this.channelMessages.remove(this.channelId);
            this.chUsers.remove(this.channelId);
        }
```

When I call deleteChannel() I have thousands console.log() from permission() function. I think the problem is change detection in Angular, but I don't know what should I do to make it work. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6696 https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24133

Comment: I tried to use changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush and assign promise to a property but it didn't work.

Comment: You should not be calling `permission` method in template because it will produce new change detection cycle every time angular checks template.

Comment: @yurzui I've added public userPermission = this.permission(this.channelId); right after class declaration, but with same result.

Comment: After class declaration? You should do it inside the class, not after it.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović I meant after `export class HomeComponent`. Maybe I should write it in some ngOn*?